# implement MessageBodyWriter for detail array list in jersey

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I want to implement `MessageBodyWriter` for detail array list.

Here is my code for resource:

```
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("testDetail")
@JsonView(JSONView.TicketView.class)
public TestDetail[] testDetail()
{
    TestDetail[]  testDetails = {new TestDetail(), new TestDetail()};
    return testDetails;
}
```

I am implementing it like :

```
public class AppArrayMessageBodyWriter  implements MessageBodyWriter<List<TestDetail>>
{
 }
```

and

```
public class AppArrayMessageBodyWriter  implements MessageBodyWriter<TestDetail[]>
{
 }
```

But this is not working.

What am I doing wrong??